# send a contact form to mail id and PostgreSQL database using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I would like to send a contactform to an emailid as well as save it to postgresql database.The following code helps me to send it to the mail id but can't save it in the database. can anyone please help me to solve this one which would be very much appreciated

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from.import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('email/', views.email, name='email'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success')

]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Comment(models.Model):
    what_about = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Phone_Number = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.what_about
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class MyCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['what_about', 'content', 'contact_email', 'Name', 'Phone_Number']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone
from.forms import MyCommentForm

def email(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyCommentForm()
    else:
        form = MyCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            subject = form.cleaned_data['what_about']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            message = 'contact_email: "{}"\n Phone_Number: "{}"\n Name: "{}"\n content: "{}"'.format(cd['contact_email'],
                                                                                                     cd['Phone_Number'],
                                                                                                     cd['Name'],
                                                                                                     cd['content'])
        try:

            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['prasanth@interloggg.net'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('success')

    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your models in the views and make "Comment.save()"

You're importing ur forms but it isn't ur database, place it in the moment where you think suit the best, save every answer to the right column.